# VBA to loop through column if the header is not empty

Tags: vba, loops

I want to start looping through each column if the column header is not blank. I don't know how to locate the header of each column as it is letter, not number.

I googled many codes but they are not doing exactly I want.

Below is the code. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
Sub ColorGradient()

'Find the last roll number
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = Range("A:A").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Dim cs As ColorScale
Dim rng As Range

'Loop through each column
For Each rng In Range("B4:AA" & Lastrow).Columns
    'Set color gradient
    Set cs = rng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=3)

    ' Set the color of the lowest value
        With cs.ColorScaleCriteria(1)
            .Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
            With .FormatColor
                .Color = RGB(248, 105, 107)
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
       
        ' In the middle
        With cs.ColorScaleCriteria(2)
            .Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
            .Value = 50
            With .FormatColor
                .Color = RGB(255, 244, 189)
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
       
        ' At the highest value
        With cs.ColorScaleCriteria(3)
            .Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
            With .FormatColor
                .Color = RGB(0, 204, 255)
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
Next rng

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand completely, but test that the "header" row value is not blank first, then set your column range and do stuff to it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim rHdrs As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim rCol As Range
Dim Lastrow As Integer

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    Lastrow = .Columns(1).Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Set rHdrs = .Range("B3:AA3")

    For Each r In rHdrs
        If r.Value <> "" Then

            Set rCol = .Range(.Cells(4, r.Column), .Cells(Lastrow, r.Column))
            'loop through cells in rCol
            'do stuff with the non-empty header column ranges here

        End If
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

I assumed you were doing this on Thisworkbook.sheets(1).

Comment: originally I have an image. But I don't have enough reputation to post it. My header is on row 3. I want to do this: Check B3. 1) if not blank, do something for column B starting on B4. 2) if blank, do nothing. Then move on to check C3.....until it loop to AA.

Comment: I changed the answer. All I had to do is change "B4:AA4" to "B3:AA3" and I added the comment "loop through cells in rCol", which you could do via a For Each rng In rCol.

Comment: I merged yours with mine, with some alternation, it worked. Thanks mountainclimber.

Comment: @Jim feel free to check my post as the answer. Thanks! :)